# Flask-Security Register Redirect

Tags: python, redirect, flask, flask-security

I have my login and register on the main page, index. When the user logs in or registers successfully, everything's gravy.

However, when there's an error, Flask-Security redirects the user to a different page, /login and /register respectively. I don't see a need to include these separate pages. How do I have Flask-Security not redirect and instead show the errors right there on the index page?

I've tried setting `SECURITY_{REGISTER,LOGIN}_USER_TEMPLATE='/index.html'` but that did not work.

Comment: can you share some code of your login,register or index view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SECURITY_{REGISTER,LOGIN}_USER_TEMPLATE` requires a template, you're specifying a URL.  So if you change it to `SECURITY_REGISTER_USER_TEMPLATE='index.html'` it'll try and render the template you mention.

But what I think you really should do, is use JSON to manage your login features since you're squidging them into a single page.

Flask-Security's login and register views look out for JSON requests, and so if you send it some, it'll in turn respond with JSON, and in the case of a bad password/bad email etc, it'll include the errors in the JSON return data, so you could then handle your logins purely via Ajax.

You can see how [the login watches for JSON in the source](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/views.py#L62-L88) and how the [returned data is rendered](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/views.py#L37-L50)